# mic recommendation for microscopic recording

Tags: microphone, microsound

which mic (or what type of mic) would you recommend for properly capturing microsound? e.g. recording really small tiny acoustic elements? i'm interested in capturing high resolution inner detail of some physical materials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may want to look into contact microphones. they can get you a lot of detail that might otherwise be lost, but it's not always easy finding the best place to attach them on small devices.

about microphones in general (and this isn't always true, but it's a starting point): large diaphragms are generally more sensitive to lower acoustic levels than small diaphragms, but small diaphragms generally have better high frequency response. that can help inform your choice of microphone.

Answer (score 4):

Might want to see if anything in this thread helps you.
[How to capture very low volume sounds?](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-to-capture-very-low-volume-sounds)

Answer (score 1):

I think the mic has been mentioned before but if you want something super sensitive the now discontinued [Sanken MO-64](http://www.atscomms.com/Sales/Products/Mics/Sanken/Contact_Mic/contact_mic.html) can record ant's footsteps and a snail's hearbeat.

What exactly are you planning on recording?  What do you mean my by inner detail of some physical materials?  I'm trying to think if you want a contact mic or a sensitive large diaphragm condenser...

Comment: the MO-64 is a great example. is there any (cheaper) equivallent for it in the market? ... i'm interested in capturing small insect sounds, elasticity of several sensitive materials such as springs, rubbergum, thick fluids, etc.

Answer (score 1):

We have a Sanken MO-64 in the studio, all I can say is...wow.